# how to get the app path of xrPictureBox image URL expression devExpress winforms?

Tags: winforms, report, devexpress

[image: the describtion in the photo]

plz i want to know the expression of the app path to  replace the statick path 'C:\Users.....'  with adynamic one like C# code "Application.StartUpPath"  the full describtion is inside this photo

Answer (score 0):

you can use the relative path 'imgs/' + [name] + '.png'
or pass the invisible parameter to the report
so the expression will be ?imgsPathParameter + '/' + [name] + '.png'